# Mutable-ish underlying collection of Map<int64, customObject>

Tags: f#

I'm trying to write an F# type that wraps an underlying collection of `Map<int64, customType>` such that I can add items to it:

```
type public CandleContainer (seedCandles:System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Candle>) = 
let candles : Map<int64, Candle> =
    seedCandles
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.Start.Ticks, x)
    |> Map.ofSeq

let candleInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0)

member public x.AddCandle (candle:Candle) = 
    candles = candles.Add(candle.Start.Ticks, candle)

member public x.GetList () : List<Candle> = 
    candles
    |> Map.toSeq
    |> Seq.map (fun (key, value) -> value)
    |> Seq.toList
```

The problem that I'm getting is in the AddCandle method. I understand that Map.Add returns a new map with the value added and the compiler isn't complaining that I'm trying to overwrite the value of candles. However, whenever I try adding a new Candle using this method x.GetList returns an empty list. Is there a way to overwrite the old value of candles with the result of the Map.Add? Or do I just make candles a mutable value and overwrite it?

Comment: I think the best way is to make candles mutable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the `mutable` keyword and `<-` operator.

Change `let candles ...` to be

```
let mutable candles : Map<int64, Candle>
```

and `candles = ...` to be

```
candles <- candles.Add(candle.Start.Ticks, candle)
```

. Also note that your previous use of  `=` where you thought replacement was occurring was actually performing an equality check, making the return type of that method `bool`.